# trouble using $.data() to change state for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everyone thank you in advance. In the below code i want to start with a #foo div having the data value = "no" and when clicked i should be able to perform an operation and change the value to "yes". Then when I click on the div again i want to change the value back to "no" and the same thing should happen for every click. what is wrong with my logic I tried to do this different ways like using attr(). I couldn't get it done

```
<div id = "foo" data-clicked="no"> #FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO </div>

            $(document).ready( function(){
```

// over here if the data atribute: `data-clicked="no"` then when I click on foo the div should change the value to yes and alert "changed to yes" in the console, which it does

```
        if($("#foo").data("clicked") === "no"){
                $("#foo").on("click",function(){
                    $("#foo").data("clicked","yes");
                    alert("changed to yes")
                    console.log($("#foo").data("clicked"))
                })




        }
```

**if the data is changed to yes why doesnt the below code evalute to true? It doesnt work**

```
        if($("#foo").data("clicked") === "yes"){
            $("#foo").on("click",function(){
                $("#foo").attr("data-clicked", "no");
                $("#foo").data("clicked","no");
                alert("off")
                console.log($("#foo").data("clicked"))
                console.log($("#foo").attr("data-clicked"))
            })
        }

         });
```

I also tried below and it didn't work... My logic?

```
                $("#foo").on("click", function(){
                if($(this).attr("data-clicked") == "no"){
                    alert("turn on");
                    $(this).attr("data-clicked", "yes") 
                }
                if($(this).attr("data-clicked") == "yes"){
                    alert("turn off")
                    $(this).attr("data-clicked", "no")
                }

            })
```

Comment: jQuery's `data` doesn't change attributes, it changes an internal store in jQuery. If this is just to create a toggle function, that's fine, if you need to change the actual attribute, you have to use `attr`. The problem with your code is that you're checking the data outside the click handler, it needs to be inside it to check it everytime a click happens

Comment: i want to change the attribute I guess because i want to assign value (on off switches) to element is it easier to do that with .attr() or data()? i want to be able to use that information for condition statement through out my code. Thanks for your coment

Comment: im checking the data inside click handlers but I guess that the data isn't being transferred between click handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are only setting the on handler based on the original value.
Putting the logic inside the function overcomes this problem (this can be done in a multitude of ways. See below examples

Example 1: Using else if

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // over here if the data atribute: data-clicked="no" then when I click on foo the div should change the value to yes and alert "changed to yes" in the console, which it does
  jQuery("#foo").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).data("clicked") === "no") {
      jQuery(this).data("clicked", "yes");
      alert("changed to yes");
      console.log(jQuery(this).data("clicked"))
    } else if ($(this).data("clicked") === "yes") {
      jQuery(this).data("clicked", "no");
      alert("off");
      console.log(jQuery(this).data("clicked"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" data-clicked="no">#FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</div>
```

Example 2: Using a switch statement

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // over here if the data atribute: data-clicked="no" then when I click on foo the div should change the value to yes and alert "changed to yes" in the console, which it does
  jQuery("#foo").on("click", function() {
    switch ($(this).data("clicked")) {
      case "no":
        jQuery(this).data("clicked", "yes");
        alert("changed to yes");
        console.log(jQuery(this).data("clicked"))
        break;
      case "yes":
        jQuery(this).data("clicked", "no");
        alert("off");
        console.log(jQuery(this).data("clicked"));
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" data-clicked="no">#FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</div>
```

Comment: that else if method really helped I hardly ever use `else if`. I thought i could do it in 2 separate if statement why cant I do it. could you show me in 2 different if statements inside the click handler I think that would be helpful. I know it's not efficient but im learning. good answer I will accept.

Comment: and i could use `$(this).data`  instead of jQuery("#foo") inside the if statement. I'm wondering why you didn't

Comment: You can't do it with two separate if statements because if the first one finds a "no" it changes it to a "yes", then the second if statement will run and change it back to "no". That's why I used else if, but actually a more robust method might be to use a switch statement, as I have in example 2.

Comment: I didn't think to, but yes you certainly should do that. Will update answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do like this.

```
<div clicked='no'> </div>

$('#foo').on('click', function(){
  $('#foo').attr('clicked') == 'no' ? $('#foo').attr('clicked', 'yes') : $('#foo').attr('clicked', 'no');
}
```

Refer about this Method : http://api.jquery.com/attr/